# Delete row from database table with Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Recently I've started with Laravel 5.2 and I'm trying to make delete button which will delete row from database. Very basic and trivial but seems I can't make it.

I'm following documentation for delete: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#deletes

And I have made this. My route:

```
Route::post('flags/destroy/{delete}', 'FlagsController@destroy')->name('admin.flags.destroy');
```

Button in the view

```
{!! Html::linkRoute('admin.flags.destroy', 'Delete', $flag->report_id) !!}
```

and the controller

```
public function destroy(Request $request){

    $report = $request['report_id'];      

    Report::find($report);

    $report->delete();        
    $request->session()->flash('alert-success', ' Report is deleted successfully.');

    return redirect()->route('admin.flags');
}
```

I've tried solutions from other threads but I always got error:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in compiled.php line 8936:

New error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'reports.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `reports` where `reports`.`id` is null limit 1
```

Why is searching for `id` instead of `report_id`?

UPDATE:

button

```
{!! Html::linkRoute('admin.flags.destroy', 'Delete', $flag->report_id) !!}
```

Controller

```
public function destroy(Request $request){

    $report = $request['report_id'];      

    dd( $request->input('delete'));

    Report::where('report_id', $report)->first();

    $report->delete();        
    $request->session()->flash('alert-success', ' Report is deleted successfully.');

    return redirect()->route('admin.flags');
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('flags/destroy/{delete}', 'FlagsController@destroy')->name('admin.flags.destroy');
```

Update 2: This seems to work but is it secure enough?
view:

```
 {!! Form::open(array('route' => array('admin.flags.destroy', $flag->report_id), 'method' => 'get')) !!}
        <button type="submit">Delete</button>
 {!! Form::close() !!}</td>
```

Controller

```
public function destroy($report_id){

  Report::destroy($report_id);
  //$request->session()->flash('alert-success', ' Report is deleted successfully.');

  return redirect()->route('admin.flags');
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your code need to update like:

```
public function destroy($delete){

   $report = $delete;      

   $rsltDelRec = Report::find($report);

   $rsltDelRec->delete();        
   $request->session()->flash('alert-success', ' Report is deleted successfully.');

   return redirect()->route('admin.flags');
}
```

Hope this work for you!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Got this `Call to a member function delete() on string
`

Comment: `dd($report);` return `"1"` i.e. string

Comment: @VLS Please check my answer. I made correction for it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Controller:

```
  public function destroy(Report $report){

          $report->delete();

          return redirect()->route('admin.flags');

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating `get` link but using `post` route. Change it to:

```
Route::get('flags/destroy/{delete}', 'FlagsController@destroy')->name('admin.flags.destroy');
```

Comment: use reports_id not reports.id.check your query

Comment: I'm using it.. check the function and query in my question. It is requesting for report)id..

Comment: check primary key in your model. it should be like protected $primaryKey = 'report_id'; // find() uses primary key // looks like you have $primaryKey = 'id'

Answer (score 1):

`MethodNotAllowedHttpException` means that you are trying to access route with bad method. If you use `Html::linkRoute` then anchor is generated, but in your routes you have defined `Route::post`. You need to replace `Route::post` with `Route::get`. But if you want to make it safer you need to create simple form with delete button and CSRF token.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ URL::route('admin.flags.destroy', {'delete' => $flag->report_id}) }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <!-- submit button -->
</form>
```

> Why is searching for id instead of report_id?

You need to replace

```
Report::find($report);
```

with

```
$report = Report::where('report_id', $report)->first();
```

---

```
public function destroy(Request $request){

    $report = $request['report_id'];
    ....
```

You are trying here to access `report_id` in request, but in routes you named your parameter as `delete`

Comment: Hm, now `Call to a member function delete() on null` this

Comment: deleting a null value

Comment: change `$request['report_id']; ` to  `$request['delete'];`

Comment: Still same. @Bugfixer I know what is mean . just can't figure out why is null and how to fix

Comment: but you assinged your model to variable like this: `$report = Report::where('report_id', $report)->first();`. Before you had only `Report::find...` without anything

Comment: first of all don't use GET in url otherwise anyone can delete all records just by using url and changing its parameter. use some kind of authentication to verify user.

Comment: Still same error `Call to a member function delete() on null` .. when I click on delete the url is `..flags/destroy/1`

Comment: Check `$request` var with `dd($report);` and the variable from request to ensure that controller getting correct id.

Comment: `dd($report);` showing `null` so the controller doesn't getting anything

Comment: Try `dd( $request->input('delete'));`

Comment: Hm, still same. `null`

Comment: @VLS I think that you should change request method to `POST` (in link form generation and routes.php) and add `{{ csrf_field() }}` to your form. This will prevent situation when someone send you a mail for ex. with delete link to your website.

Comment: With csrf I see in source this `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="S6SpWJUnfZMsNEFbm95UzkZksjl1w6lCVVz6f9tF">` how this will prevent some situations since I can see it on source code of the page?

Comment: But someone who can send you mail, cant predict your token. They are unique and connected to your current session.